# Display Multiple Images with Single Answer

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I am working on the below code, where the same question can have multiple images as an answer.

So, they are displaying properly but, with every image, the same question is repeating multiple times.

So, I want the question to display only once and below that the answers should be displayed. Below is the code. I have created a table and the images will be displayed after the question. Same has been highlighted below. I have done some POC, please have a look.

```
<!--Question and Answer Section Open-->
@if($submited_documents->count() !=0)
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tbody>
            @if(count($submited_documents) > 0)
                @foreach($submited_documents as $documents)
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width:50% !important; border:1px solid lightgray;"><strong>Question{{$documents->sequence}} : </strong></th>
                        <th style="border:1px solid lightgray; "><strong>Answer : </strong></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $documents->question }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $documents->comments }}</td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            @endif
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($submited_documents as $documents)
                <tr>
                    <td style="border-radius: 2px;">
                        <strong>Question{{$documents->sequence}} : </strong>{{ $documents->question }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                @if(count($documents->pictures) > 0 )
                    @foreach($documents->pictures as $document_picture)
                        <tr>
                            <td class="td_class">
                                @if($document_picture->filename != null)
                                    <a style="" href="{{ URL::to('public/uploads/pickups/'.$document_picture->filename) }}" target="new">
                                    <img src="{{ URL::to('public/uploads/pickups/'.$document_picture->filename) }}"
                                         alt="{{ $document_picture->filename }}" title="{{ $document_picture->filename  }}"
                                         style="width: 50% !important;height: 50% !important;" ></a><br>
                                @endif
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                @endif
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
@endif
<!--Question and Answer Section End-->
```

Any help is appreciated..

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what the result is

Comment: Can you please post output screenshot so that base I can guide you.

Comment: Sure.But, How can I add docs file

Comment: just take a screenshot and add it as image of what your outputting

Comment: Thanx to all for your reply. I have resolved issue by myself.

The only thing I need to do is to check if count of images are == 0 then it should not display question and hence I resolved.